# Java - обращение к полю подкласса, если его экземпляр присвоен ссылке на супер-класс и поля имеют одинаковые имена и дефолтный модификатор доступа

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм

Изучая наследование и полиморфизм в java наткнулся на такой пример:

```
class A {
 int a = 5;
 String doA() {
  return“ a1“;
 }
 protected static String doA2() {
  return“ a2“;
 }
}
class B extends A {
 int a = 7;
 String doA() {
  return“ b1“;
 }
 public static String doA2() {
  return“ b2“;
 }
 void go() {
  A myA = new B();
  System.out.print(myA.doA() + myA.doA2() + myA.a);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new B().go();
 }
}
```

Результат выполнения программы: "b1 a2 5"

1. b1 - тут понятно. фактический тип класса является B, через динамическое связывание компилятор вызывает метод doA(), определенный в классе B.
2. a2 - метод doA2() определен статическим, соответственно происходит ранее связывание, компилятор вызывает метод класса A, а не экземпляра
3. 5 - вот тут-то для меня и происходит магия. почему не 7? переменная не static и не final? фактический тип класса B

Comment: Nikolaev  А этот код компилируется?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A myA = new B();`
`^`
Потому что поля в `Java` не являются полиморфными, соответственно используется класс указателя, в данном случае это класс `A`.

По поводу методов: в `Java` все методы являются виртуальными, соответственно используется динамическое (или, как его еще называют, позднее) связывание. Поэтому на этапе выполнения `JVM` определяет тип объекта `B`, на который ссылается указатель `myA` и вызывает соответствующую реализацию метода `doA()` класса `B`.

Answer (score 4):

Если вкратце, то всё дело в том, что у вас одинаковые имена переменных и вы фактически имеете две переменные с именем `a` и происходит [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), т.е. когда одна переменная перекрывает другую. В вашем же случае происходит еще и случай описанный в [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1):

> If an expression name consists of a single Identifier, then there must
>   be exactly one visible declaration denoting either a local variable,
>   parameter or field in scope at the point at which the the Identifier
>   occurs. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> If the declaration declares a final field, the meaning of the name is
>   the value of that field. Otherwise, the meaning of the expression name
>   is the variable declared by the declaration.

Т.е. переменная ищется в скопе класса `A`, даже если это фактически является классом `B`. Если же вы хотите, чтобы менялось значение переменной для класса `B`. То надо сделать, например, так:

```
class B extends A {
    //int a = 7;

    B() {
        a = 7;
    }

    // весь остальной код
}
```

Comment: По-моему, ссылка на [jls-8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) тут тоже уместна, например абзац `A hidden field can be accessed by using a qualified name (§6.5.6.2) if it is static, or by using a field access expression that contains the keyword super (§15.11.2) or a cast to a superclass type. `

Answer (score 2):

Тип класса B, но в данном случае он скастован к классу A, а поскольку и в A и в B поле a приватное (по умолчанию, без модификатора, оно приватное), то мы обращаемся к переменной a именно класса A, где оно равно 5

Comment: Оно не приватное. оно дефолтное.